# How to set a bot's status per guild discord.js

Tags: discord.js

How to set a bot's status per guild discord.js
I want to set a bot's status per guild discord.js
I now mee6 do it also

Answer (score 1):

You would have to shard your bot to have multiple status'. This is the closest you can get to "per-guild status", you *could* assign a shard to each individual guild.

[Discord.JS Guide on Sharding](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/)